# using On success function in Jquery Ajax call

Tags: ajax, jquery

I have a .js class named Widget.js
In widget.js class I am initiating a errors.ascx control class that has a JS script function "GetErrors()" defined in it.
Now, when I call GetErrors from my widgets.js class it works perfectly fine.
I have to populate a few controls in widgets.js using the output from GetErrors() function.
But the issue is that at times the GetErrors() takes a lot of time to execute and the control runs over to my widgets class. and the controls are populated without any data in them.

So the bottom line is that I need to know the exact usage of the OnSuccess function of Jquery.

this is my errors.ascx code

```
var WidgetInstance = function () {
        this.GetErrors = function () {
                       $.ajax({
                url: '/Management/GetLoggedOnUsersByMinutes/',
                type: 'GET',
                cache: false,
                success: function (result) {
                    result = (typeof (result) == "object") ? result : $.parseJSON(result);
                    loggedOnUsers = result;
                }
            });
        },.....
```

The code for the Widgets.js file is

```
function CreateWidgetInstance() {
    widgetInstance = new WidgetInstance();
    widgetInstance.GetErrors();
    }
```

now I want that The control should move from

```
widgetInstance.GetErrors();
```

only when it has produced the results.

any Help???

Comment: Call the function that creates the controls inside the `success` callback. That's what callbacks are there for.

Comment: Hi Check my answer if it is useful for u... I suggested using `async` property in AJAX call...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a simple solution for this.. 
I just called my populating functions in the onSuccess event of the GetErrors() of my control and everything worked perfectly..

Answer (score 2):

You can use jQuery [Deferreds](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/). $.ajax() actually returns a promise. So you can do the following:

```
var WidgetInstance = function () {
    this.GetErrors = function () {
                   return $.ajax({
                            url: '/Management/GetLoggedOnUsersByMinutes/',
                            type: 'GET',
                            cache: false
                   });
    },.....
```

Then you can process the results like so...

```
widgetInstance.GetErrors().done(function(result){
    //process the resulting data from the request here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi Simply use `async:false` in your AJAX call.. It will block the control till the response reaches the client end...

```
var WidgetInstance = function () {
        this.GetErrors = function () {
                       $.ajax({
                url: '/Management/GetLoggedOnUsersByMinutes/',
                type: 'GET',
                cache: false,
                async: false,
                success: function (result) {
                    result = (typeof (result) == "object") ? result : $.parseJSON(result);
                    loggedOnUsers = result;
                }
            });
        },.....
```

Comment: Which is especially bad if the Ajax  call takes a long time, since it freezes the browser UI.

Comment: @FelixKling: yeah.. You are right.. But it was the actual requirement...Right?

Comment: I don't know, it does not say anything about this. But even if they were, it would be better not to use `async: false` ;) In the worse case, the browser will ask the user to terminate the script because the script is running too long.

Comment: NO I can't use Asyn: false since there are a number of other AJAX calls also running parallel that needs to be looked upon

Comment: @Monga: So Better place the scripts (that need to be run after the results were produced) inside a js function and call it inside the success callback of AJAX call... I found no other solutions better than this,